# How do I build a program to store a name, age and date of birth?

Tags: database-design, database-connection, frontend, backend, web-frontend

I'm a new to making programs and I am trying to understand which languages I should use to build a program that takes a persons name, age and date of birth and stores this in a database.

I can program in python and SQL, however, I don't know how I would connect the python frontend to a SQL backend.

I have created a python and HTML frontend page which takes this input, however, after this I do not understand how to set up the link to a SQL database.

Comment: Hi, you need to break down several tasks, i suggest to read this: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world, includes setting the front and back, communication with DB, and more advanced features like simple security, and deploying for production.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this. Will try the blog and if possible ask you some questions around it. Thanks again!

Comment: Read up on it, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp